# DatabaseProviderFactory of EnterpriseLibrary 6 with MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, enterprise-library-6

`DatabaseFactory` previously used `ConnectionString` to create database. Now `DatabaseProviderFactory` uses `ConfigurationSource` which basically works on *MVC 5* structure of **web.config** in XML form.

Previously we could do something like below:

```
   string stConnName = Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"];
   string stProvider = Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ProviderName"];
   Database oDb = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(stConnName);
```

Any idea about how to get JSON based database configurations as currently being mentioned in **MVC 6** *(appsettings.json)* for EnterpriseLibrary 6 `DatabaseProviderFactory`, in order to create generic Database, something like below, which only works with MVC 5's **web.config** files of XML form:

```
    FileConfigurationSource fileConfig = new FileConfigurationSource("web.config");
    DatabaseProviderFactory dbProvider = new DatabaseProviderFactory(fileConfig);
    Database oDb = dbProvider.Create("DefaultConnection");
```

Comment: I tried to Add Enterprise Library to MVC6 but it is not supported 
,if you asking how to get ConnectionString in Appsetting.Json 
Here is now I do it 
in Startup.cs  'code' public static string ConnectionString { get; private set; } 'code' and in Constructor  I set the value 'code' ConnectionString = Configuration.Get<string>("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString");'code' I wish this help

Comment: I couldn't get the answer to this so left this approach and used Custom solution. Getting Connection string was not an issue, I couldn't find the Enterprise Library approach for using Connection string. As it only uses Connection String Name.